# Unsupported operand types: array + App\StockOut Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections, eager-loading

I wanna ask why I my query isn't work when I try in another case, I have query like this :

```
$getData = StockOut::select("*",
        StockOut::raw('group_concat(stock_outs.id_stock_out) as id_stock_outs'),
    )
    ->with(['stock_ins' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id_stock_in', 'stock_in_id_type')
        ->with(['type_of_items' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id_type_item', 'type_id_item', 'code_type_of_item', 'type_of_item');
        }]);
    }])
    ->groupBy('stock_outs.stock_out_id_stock_in')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('stock_ins.stock_in_id_type')->map(function ($group) {
        return [
            'id_stock_ins' => $group->pluck('stock_ins.id_stock_in')->join(','),
            'id_stock_outs' => $group->pluck('id_stock_outs')->join(',')
        ] + $group->first();
    })->values();
```

I have error like this :

```
message: "Unsupported operand types: array + App\StockOut"
```

In StockOut model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StockOut extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "id_stock_out";

    protected $fillable = [
        'stock_out_id_location', 'stock_out_id_stock_in', 'date_of_stock_out', 'quantity', 'description', 'created_by', 'edited_by'
    ];

    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Location', 'stock_out_id_location');
    }

    public function stock_ins()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\StockIn', 'stock_out_id_stock_in');
    } 
}
```

I really don't understand about my error now, because when I try my query in another project is working and nothing error happened, I hope someone can help me to guide me solve my problem, Thank you before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check value on $group. It must be of type array in order for + operator to work.
Currently you might be doing

```
[/* ... */] + <an eloquent model>
```

which will give you that error

Comment: so in `$group` the type must be an array sir? I will check first, thanks for giving your text

Comment: Not sure what that code does. Anyways, the plus sign in your code is array union operator (not concat)  and it requires left and right operands to be arrays https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php.

Comment: Sir it's working when I try to change my query result into an array, I think I must more be careful, thank you